# Angular CLI did not give output

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I'm using angular cli 1.4.3, node 6.11.3, npm 5.4.2, I'm trying to read the records from rest API but it did not give output at localhost. There is no error arise in dev console output. Below is the code and screenshot:

read-products.component.html

```
<div class="row m-b-18px">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- button to create new product -->
    <a (click)="createProduct()" class='btn btn-primary pull-right'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Create Product
    </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

    <!-- HTML table for our list of product records -->
    <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>

        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>

        <!-- Use *ngFor directive to loop throught our list of products. -->
        <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td>{{product.price}}</td>
            <td>{{product.description}}</td>
            <td>{{product.category_name}}</td>
            <td>
                <!-- read one product button -->
                <a (click)="readOneProduct(product.id)" class='btn btn-
                primary m-r-5px'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span> Read
                </a>

                <!-- edit product button -->
                <a (click)="updateProduct(product.id)" class='btn btn-info 
                m-r-5px'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit
                </a>

                <!-- delete product button -->
                <a (click)="deleteProduct(product.id)" class='btn btn-danger 
                m-r-5px'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Delete
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

read-products.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from 
'@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Product } from '../product';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-read-products',
   templateUrl: './read-products.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./read-products.component.css'],
   providers: [ProductService]
})

export class ReadProductsComponent implements OnInit {

// store list of products
products: Product[];

// initialize productService to retrieve list products in the ngOnInit()
constructor(private productService: ProductService){}

// methods that we will use later
createProduct(){}
readOneProduct(id){}
updateProduct(id){}
deleteProduct(id){}

// Read products from API.
ngOnInit(){
    this.productService.readProducts()
        .subscribe(products =>
            this.products=products['records']
        );
}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<!-- container -->
<div class="container">

<!-- show page header -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class='page-header'><h1>{{title}}</h1></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Show this view if "show_read_products_html" property of AppComponent is 
true. -->
<app-read-products
    *ngIf="show_read_products_html">
</app-read-products>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
// properties for child components
title="Read Products";

// properties used to identify what views to show
show_read_products_html=true;
}
```

product.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Product } from './product';

@Injectable()

// Service for products data.
export class ProductService {

// We need Http to talk to a remote server.
constructor(private _http : Http){ }

// Get list of products from remote server.
readProducts(): Observable<Product[]>{
    return this._http
        .get("http://localhost/Rest%20API/product/read.php")
        .map(res => res.json());
   }

}
```

product.ts

```
// Product class to define this object's properties.
export class Product {
constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public price: number,
    public description: string,
    public category_id: number,
    public category_name: string
){}
}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Thank you.

Comment: show the dev console output, there is an error I suppose

Comment: Please don't provide links to screenshots of code; paste the actual code in your question (and use the `{}` button to format it)

Comment: there is no error arise on dev console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got figured out how to solve this, need to import http module

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
@NgModule({
declarations: [ AppComponent, ReadProductsComponent ],
imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This simple http get request will help you**

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }

getIp(): Promise<Hero[]> {
     return this.http.get("http://ipinfo.io")
         .toPromise()
         .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
         })
         .catch(this.handleError);
 }

 private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
      console.error('An error occurred', error); 
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
```

**output Will be :**

```
{
    "ip": "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx",
    "city": "Chennai",
    "region": "Tamil Nadu",
    "country": "IN",
    "loc": "17.0833,84.2833",
    "org": "AS4755 TATA COMM MAINTAINER"
}
```